# Create with inline in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms, django-views

I have two related models Train and Passenger in Django 1.7.

The passenger model has a ForeignKey to Train.

I want to make a view to create passengers and choose in which train the passenger should be placed. The problem is that sometimes the train already exists and other times it needs to be created.

How can I do all this in the same view?

I think I both need a `<select>` element to choose a train and all the input elements to create train. If an option is selected in the `<select>` element then all the input fields for createing the train will be disabled with javascript.

Is this the best approach to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would make a form for creating a train in the view and a select train list, updating the select train list if a new train is created aswell as inputs/dropdowns/checkboxes for passangers.

Note that the creating train form then should be an ajax call.